# Where do my non-action/controller classes go in a bundle?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm really new to Symfony 2, coming from CI and trying to get me head around where the correct places for everything should go. I've got a bundle that takes care of the few main page types I have, but here's one page element that I use in multiple pages, that can have different configurations for each page.

The logical way around this (as far as I can see) is to have a single class somewhere that all the pages can use... this isn't to be accessed by users so shouldn't go in the controller I'm guessing but where should I put this class?

1. Make a 'core' type folder within my bundle. Are there naming best practices for this?
2. Should it go in the vendor folder or is this just for third party bundles?
3. Make another bundle to somehow use this code... seems a bit overkill for one or two classes?
4. other?

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you need is to create a service. You can create your own class that has it's own logic and retrieve it using the service container in the controller. The following example is available at [Symfony Service Container Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

```
$mailer = $this->get('my_mailer');
$mailer->send('ryan@foobar.net', ...);
```

To make that class available you have to add it in the service.yml file of your bundle like this:

```
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        "%my_mailer.class%"
        arguments:    ["%my_mailer.transport%"]
```

You can add any other service or parameter to your class via the arguments

More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html